Does $\#\text{Ker}(f^*)\le \#\text{Im}(f)$ hold? Duality of profinite group
Let $M, M'$ be a profinite groups.
Let $M^*=\text{Hom}_{conti}(M,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$ be a dual of $M$.
Let $f:M\to M'$ be a homomorphism of abelian group.
Let  $f^*: M'^*\to M^*$ be a map defined by $g\to g \circ f$.
Does $\#\text{Ker}(f^*)\le \#\text{Im}(f)$ hold　under some mild condition on  $M, M'$ or unconditionally?
I know $(\text{Im}(f))^* \cong \text{Im}(f^*)$ and $\#\text{Ker}(f^*)=\#\text{Im}(f)$ does not hold in general.
My try :
If
(1) : Annihilator of $\text{Im}(f)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Ker}(\hat{f})$.
(2) : Annihilator of $\text{Im}(f)$ does not incerease than $\text{Im}(f)$
holds, then we are done, but  I don't have confident on these two process.
Thank you for your help.

Do you mean $g\longmapsto g\circ f$?

@Arturo Magidin. Thank you very much. I modified my question.

What is the motivation for your question?
You must intend your profinite groups to be abelian, since working with continuous homomorphisms to $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ can only see $M$ as far as its abelianizaion $M/[M,M]$.
Did you look at your question first when the groups are finite abelian?
When $G$ is a finite abelian group, with subgroup $H$, the map $G^* \to H^*$ given by restriction of characters on $G$ to the domain $H$ is a homomorphism that is onto with kernel $H^\perp := \{\chi \in G^* : \chi = 1 \ {\rm on } \ H\}$, so $G^*/H^\perp \cong H^*$. Thus $|H^\perp| = |G^*|/|H^*| = |G|/|H|$.
When $f : G_1 \to G_2$ is a homomorphism of finite abelian groups, with dual homomorphism $f^* : G_2^* \to G_1^*$, ${\rm im}(f)$ is a subgroup of $G_2$ and $\ker(f^*)$ is a subgroup of $G_2^*$. These subgroups of $G_2$ and $G_2^*$ are annihilators of each other, so  $({\rm im}\, f)^\perp = \ker(f^*)$.  (Similarly, $(\ker f)^\perp = {\rm im}(f^*)$ in $G_1^*$.)
Thus $|\ker(f^*)| = |({\rm im}\, f)^\perp| = |G_2|/|{\rm im}f|$, so $|\ker(f^*)| \leq |{\rm im}\, f|$ if and only if $|{\rm im}\, f|^2 \leq |G_2|$.

Thank you very much. I am motivated by the case where both $G$ and $H$ are infinite groups, but $\text{Im}(f)$ is finite. I want to prove that $#{\text{Ker}(f^*)}$ is finite and is not larger than $#\text{Im}(f)$. Perhaps the same argument from your answer could work well in my case?

But in my case, $\text{Im}f^\cong G_2/(\text{Im}(f))^ ⊥$ and $\text{Im}(f)$ is finite group. This implies $#\text{Ker}(f^)=#(\text{Im}(f))^ ⊥$ is infinite and what I tried  to prove is false ?

Do you know even one example of what you're trying to find conditions for?

The example in my head is a bit more complex, involving Galois cohomology of elliptic curves, but for this question, I have simplified the situation to merely a group theory problem. Let $K$ be a number field and $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$. What in my mind is $G_1=H^2(G_K,E[2])^, G_1=H^1(G_K,E[2])$. Both are infinite group, but there is a complicated map $ε : G_1\to G_2$ such that $\text{Im}(ε)$ is finite order $n$. And it should in fact holds $#\text{Ker}(ε^)=n$ according to 'Cohomology of number fields'. But as above, something is going wrong.

Here, $n$ is exactly the order of 2-Selmer group $\text{Sel}^2(E/K)$.

When $G$ and $H$ are profinite abelian groups and $f : G \to H$ is a continuous homomorphism, $({\rm im} , f)^\perp = \ker(f^)$. Also $({\rm im}, f)^\perp \cong (H/{\rm im}, f)^$, so if $\ker(f^)$ is finite then $(H/{\rm im}, f)^$ is finite. That implies $H/{\rm im}, f$ is finite. So if ${\rm im}, f$ is finite and $\ker(f^*)$ is finite then ${\rm im},f$ and $H/{\rm im},f$ are finite, which implies $H$ is finite.

Thank you very much. Yes, then, $H^1(G_K,E[2])$ is finite, but this is absurd. I may misread some thing.. ? This $ε$ appears in p491 of cohomology of number fields, and $\text{Im}(ε)$ is finite. On the other hand, Cassels states $\text{Ker}(ε^*)$ is also finite, contradiction..
